# remove "profile" admin-menu from administrative panel

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress, and I want to remove "profile" menu-option completely

Any one is having idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Profiless](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/profiless/) plugin does that on the subscriber-level.
If you wish to do that for other groups, you should probably use it in combination with [Capability manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/) plugin.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, here's how to do it programmatically...

```
// Run the function on admin_init
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_profile_menu');

// Removal function
function remove_profile_menu() {
  global $wp_roles;

  // Remove the menu. Syntax is `remove_submenu_page($menu_slug, $submenu_slug)`
  remove_submenu_page('users.php', 'profile.php');

  /* Remove the capability altogether. Syntax is `remove_cap($role, $capability)`
   * 'Read' is the only capability subscriber has by default, and allows access
   * to the Dashboard and Profile page. You can also remove from a specific user
   * like this:
   * $user = new WP_User(null, $username);
   * $user->remove_cap($capability); 
   */
  $wp_roles->remove_cap('subscriber', 'read');
}
```

Comment: This removes access to the admin completely, which isn't necessarily what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late but I just stumbled on this and thought I would add to it.  That does remove the sub-menu profile menu item but does not remove the menu profile item.  For someone like me who has created a completely custom profile page, I don't want my users to access the profile.php page at all.  So this code will work for that:

```
function remove_profile_menu() {

    remove_submenu_page('users.php', 'profile.php');
    remove_menu_page('profile.php');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_profile_menu');
```

And if you only want to do this for certain capabilities....use this code:

```
function remove_profile_menu() {

    // Only the Admin can see the profile menu
    if(!current_user_can('update_core')) {

    remove_submenu_page('users.php', 'profile.php');
    remove_menu_page('profile.php');

    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_profile_menu');
```

You can use the current_user_can() function to determine who you want to see the menu items.

Comment: Just learned something new...using the admin_init action will cause some ajax errors in your site due to the menu not being called yet.  Therefore, instead use this action:  add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_profile_menu');